# React and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple app using `ReactJS` and `Socket.io`

In my component I want to be able to communicate with the server, but the problem is that I don't know how to do `io.connect()`

1.Do I need to explicitly specify the IP address like `io.connect("http://myHost:7000")` or is it enough to say : `io.connect()` ? As we can see in this piece of code : 
https://github.com/DanialK/ReactJS-Realtime-Chat/blob/master/client/app.jsx

2.I do more or less the same as this code , but I receive error when I do `npm start` as `io is undefined`. I think , `io` is provided globally by including the `socket.io` script. How can I solve this problem ?

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
var socket = io.connect();
var chatWindow = React.createClass({

    displayName: 'chatWindow',

    propTypes: {},

    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return ({
            messages: 0
        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        socket = this.props.io.connect();
        socket.on('value', this._messageRecieve);
    },
    _messageRecieve: function(messages) {
        this.setState({
           messages: messages
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return ({
            messages: 0
        });
    },
    _handleSend: function(){
        var newValue = parseInt(this.refs.messageBox.value) + this.props.messages;
        this.setState({
            messages: newValue
        });
        socket.emit('clientMessage', { message: newValue});
    },
    render: function() {
        var window =
                <div>
                    <div>{this.props.messages}</div>
                    <input type="text" id="messageBox" refs="messageBox"></input>
                    <input type="button" onClick={this._handleSend} value="send" id="send"/>
                </div>;
        return (window);
    }
});

module.exports = chatWindow;
```

This is the code :

https://github.com/arian-hosseinzadeh/simple-user-list

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried so far?

Comment: In your question, not links to github please. Provide a self-contained example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers:

1) No, you don't need to specify the IP, you can even use `/` and it will go through the default HTTP 80 port, anyway, you can find more examples on the socket.io site.

2) Require `io` too, remember to add [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) to your package:

```
var React = require('react'),
    io    = require('socket.io-client');
```

Anyway, if you want to include the client script that socket.io server provides as a static file, then remember to add it into your HTML using a `<script/>` tag, that way you'll have **io** on the global scope avoiding the require part, but well, I prefer to require it.

**NOW, WHAT ABOUT...**

Trying my lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-socket

It will handle the socket connection on mount and disconnection on unmount (the same goes for socket event listeners), give it a try and let me know.

Here you have an example:

http://coma.github.io/react-socket/

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {

        return {
            tweets: []
        };
    },
    onTweet: function(tweet) {

        var tweets = this
            .state
            .tweets
            .slice();

        tweet.url    = 'https://twitter.com/' + tweet.user + '/status/' + tweet.id;
        tweet.at     = new Date(tweet.at);
        tweet.avatar = {
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + tweet.img + ')'
        };

        tweets.unshift(tweet);

        this.setState({
            tweets: tweets
        });
    },
    renderTweet: function (tweet) {

        return (
            <li key={tweet.id}>
                <a href={tweet.url} target="_blank">
                    <div className="user">
                        <div className="avatar" style={ tweet.avatar }/>
                        <div className="name">{ tweet.user }</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text">{ tweet.text }</div>
                </a>
            </li>
        );
    },
    render: function () {

        return (
            <div>
                <ReactSocket.Socket url="http://tweets.socket.io"/>
                <ReactSocket.Event name="tweet" callback={ this.onTweet }/>
                <ul className="tweets">{ this.state.tweets.map(this.renderTweet) }</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks for disclosing your affiliation - best to provide some code examples of how this solves the OP's problem too though.

Comment: @remus, THANK YOU for commenting instead of downvoting, well done.

Comment:  I like helping not being a dick haha

Comment: It returns me this error when I require `socket.io-client` and assign it to `io` : `url.js:29
if (null == uri) uri = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host; TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined`

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh, replace loc with location.

Comment: Actually this is part of `socket.io-client`

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh, check that you are using an stable socket.io-client version, the one I'm using it's ok, you can see that it's working.

Comment: I guess the problem was that I didn't set ip address and port in `io.connect()`